# Fill the holes in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, opencv, flood-fill

I have an edge map extracted from edge detection module in [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/) (canny edge detection). What I want to do is to fill the holes in the edge map.

I am using **C++**, and **OpenCV** libraries. In OpenCV there is a [cvFloodFill()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_processing.html?highlight=cvfloodfill#cvFloodFill) function, and it will fill the holes with a seed (with one of the location to start flooding). However, I am trying to fill all the interior holes without knowing the seeds.(similar to [imfill()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) in MATLAB)

**Q1:** how to find all the seeds, so that I could apply 'cvFloodFill()'?
**Q2:** how to implement a 'imfill()' equivalent?

Newbie in OpenCV, and any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) in MATLAB:

> ```
> BW2 = imfill(BW,'holes');
> ```
>
> fills holes in the binary image `BW`.
>   A hole is a set of background pixels that cannot be reached by filling in the background from the edge of the image.

Therefore to get the "holes" pixels, make a call to [`cvFloodFill`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill) with the left corner pixel of the image as a seed. You get the holes by complementing the image obtained in the previous step.

#### MATLAB Example:

```matlab
BW = im2bw( imread('coins.png') );
subplot(121), imshow(BW)

% used here as if it was cvFloodFill
holes = imfill(BW, [1 1]);    % [1 1] is the starting location point

BW(~holes) = 1;               % fill holes
subplot(122), imshow(BW)
```

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Very nice.  I was trying to figure out how to do this without relying on the `holes` flag in `imfill`.  I'd like to do this on OpenCV Python and you have shown me the way.  Thanks Amro!

Answer (score 12):

the cvDrawContours function has an option to fill the contours that you have drawn.

Here is a short example
    cvDrawContours( IplImage, contours, color, color, -1, CV_FILLED, 8 );

Here is the documentation

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html?highlight=cvdrawcontours#cvDrawContours

I guess you posted this a long time ago, but I hope it helps someone.

This is the source code (in C#):

```
        Image<Gray, byte> image = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"D:\final.bmp");
        CvInvoke.cvShowImage("image 1", image);

        var contours = image.FindContours();
        while (contours != null)
        {
            CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(image, contours, new Gray(255).MCvScalar, new Gray (255).MCvScalar, 0, -1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.CV_AA, new DPoint(0, 0));
            contours = contours.HNext;
        }
        CvInvoke.cvShowImage("image 2", image);
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

I've been looking around the internet to find a proper **imfill** function (as the one in Matlab) but working in C++ with OpenCV. After some reaserches, I finally came up with a solution :

```
IplImage* imfill(IplImage* src)
{
    CvScalar white = CV_RGB( 255, 255, 255 );

    IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), 8, 3);
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvSeq* contour = 0;

    cvFindContours(src, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
    cvZero( dst );

    for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next )
    {
        cvDrawContours( dst, contour, white, white, 0, CV_FILLED);
    }

    IplImage* bin_imgFilled = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), 8, 1);
    cvInRangeS(dst, white, white, bin_imgFilled);

    return bin_imgFilled;
}
```

For this: [Original Binary Image](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/4715/originalbinaryimage.jpg)

Result is: [Final Binary Image](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/5681/finallbinaryimage.jpg)

The trick is in the parameters setting of the cvDrawContours function:
cvDrawContours( dst, contour, white, white, 0, CV_FILLED);

- dst = destination image
- contour = pointer to the first contour
- white = color used to fill the contour
- 0 = Maximal level for drawn contours. If 0, only contour is drawn
- CV_FILLED = Thickness of lines the contours are drawn with. If it is negative (For example, =CV_FILLED), the contour interiors are drawn.

More info in the openCV documentation.

There is probably a way to get "dst" directly as a binary image but I couldn't find how to use the cvDrawContours function with binary values.

Answer (score 7):

I made a simple function that is equivalent to matlab's imfill('holes'). I've not tested it for many cases, but it has worked so far. I'm using it on edge images but it accepts any kind of binary image, like from a thresholding operation.

A hole is no more than a set of pixels that cannot be "reached" when background is filled, so,

```
void fillEdgeImage(cv::Mat edgesIn, cv::Mat& filledEdgesOut) const
{
    cv::Mat edgesNeg = edgesIn.clone();

    cv::floodFill(edgesNeg, cv::Point(0,0), CV_RGB(255,255,255));
    bitwise_not(edgesNeg, edgesNeg);
    filledEdgesOut = (edgesNeg | edgesIn);

    return;
}
```

Here is an example result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick and dirty approach:

1. Perform canny on your input image so that the new binary image has 1's at the edges, and 0's otherwise
2. Find the first 0 along a side of your edge image, and initiate a floodfill with 1's at that point on a blank image using your edge image as the mask. (We're hoping here that we didn't get unlucky and seed this first fill on the inside of a shape that is half-off the screen)
3. This new floodfilled image is the 'background'. Any pixel here that has a 1 is the background, and any pixel that has a 0 is the foreground.
4. Loop through the image and find any foreground pixels. Seed a floodfill on any you find.
5. OR this new floodfilled image with your Canny image from step 1, and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Just an appendix for [Amro's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1717015/1194873)

```
void cvFillHoles(cv::Mat &input)
{
    //assume input is uint8 B & W (0 or 1)
    //this function imitates imfill(image,'hole')
    cv::Mat holes=input.clone();
    cv::floodFill(holes,cv::Point2i(0,0),cv::Scalar(1));
    for(int i=0;i<input.rows*input.cols;i++)
    {
        if(holes.data[i]==0)
            input.data[i]=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of looping, you could subtract from 255 to complement a CV_8U binary image, equivalent to: holes = 255 - holes

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ContourFinding over the Cannyied Image?

cvFindContours creates sort of a tree in which the outer countours are parents to the inner contours ('holes'). See contours.py sample. From the contours you could extract seeds

Comment: I'm trying exactly this, it doesn't work: `FindContours` identifies a lot of fake contours where there is a sharp turn of the edges, so you can't label them accurately.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I'am also finding the solution to this problem. Here I implemented [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) 's idea as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    IplImage *im = cvLoadImage("coin.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    IplImage *hole = cvCreateImage(cvSize(im->width,im->height),8,1);
    cvShowImage("Original",im);

    cvCopyImage(im,hole);
    cvFloodFill(hole,cvPoint(0,0),cvScalar(255));
    cvShowImage("Hole",hole);
    cvSaveImage("hole.png",hole);

    cvNot(hole,hole);
    cvAdd(im,hole,im);
    cvShowImage("FillHole",im);
    cvSaveImage("fillHole.png",im);

    cvWaitKey(0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: This unfortunately uses also the C API of OpenCV which will soon be deprecated. Do not use it anymore, except when you have some *very* specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the points from the edges you can use **fillConvexPoly() or fillPoly()** (if poly not convex).

One way to get the points from edges is to do **findContours() -> approxPolyDP()**.