# Python 2.7: Area opening and closing binary image in Python not so accurate

Tags: python-2.7, matlab, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I am using Python 2.7 and I used following Python and Matlab function for removing noises and fill holes in this image

[image].

*1. Code to remove noise and fill holes using Python and Opencv*

```
img = cv2.imread("binar.png",0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
open = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(open, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

2. Code used in python and scipy using *ndimage.binary_closing*:

   ```
     im = cv2.imread("binar.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    open_img = ndimage.binary_opening(im)
    close_img = ndimage.binary_closing(open_img)
    clg = close_img.astype(np.int)
   ```
3. Code used in Matlab: I used *imfill* and *bwareaopen*.

The results I got is shown below:

First image from using *nd.image.binary_closing*. My problem is it doesn't fill all white blobs fully. We can see inbetween minor black portion are still present.
[image]

Second image from using *cv2.morphologyEx*. Same problem in this also, as it also has some minor white portion in between white blobs. Here I faced one more problem. It converts some white pixels into black which should not be otherwise. I mentioned those areas with red color in image 2. Red highlighted portions is connected with larger one blobs but even then they get converted into black pixels.[image]

Third image I got from MATLAB processing in which imfill work perfectly without converting essential white pixels into black.[image]

So, my question is, Is there any method for Python 2.7 with which I can remove noises below certain area and fill the white blobs accurately as in Matlab? One more thing is, I want to find out the centroids and areas of those final processed blobs in last for further used. I can find out these using *cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats* but I want to find area and centroids after removing noises and filling blobs.

Thanks.

(I think this is not duplicate because I want to do it in Python not in Matlab. )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill the binary image without imfill function in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316961/fill-the-binary-image-without-imfill-function-in-matlab)

Comment: You can try to translate the MATLAB code to Python. Moreover, the first answer is an algorithm not MATLAB code. You can try to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Matlab's `imfill()` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html):

> `BW2= imfill(BW,locations)` performs a flood-fill operation on background pixels of the input binary image BW, starting from the points specified in locations. (...)
>
> `BW2= imfill(BW,'holes')` fills holes in the input binary image BW. In this syntax, a hole is a set of background pixels that cannot be reached by filling in the background from the edge of the image.
>
> `I2= imfill(I)` fills holes in the grayscale image I. In this syntax, a hole is defined as an area of dark pixels surrounded by lighter pixels.

The duplicate that I flagged shows ways to accomplish the third variant usually. However for many images, the second variant will still work fine and is extremely easy to accomplish. From the first variant you see that it mentions a *flood-fill operation*, which can be implemented in OpenCV with [`cv2.floodFill()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill). The second variant gives a really easy method---just flood fill from the edges, and the pixels left over are the black holes which can't be reached from outside. Then if you invert this image, you'll get white pixels for the holes, which you can add to your mask to fill in the holes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image, ensure binary
img = cv2.imread('image.png', 0)
img[img!=0] = 255

# flood fill background to find inner holes
holes = img.copy()
cv2.floodFill(holes, None, (0, 0), 255)

# invert holes mask, bitwise or with img fill in holes
holes = cv2.bitwise_not(holes)
filled_holes = cv2.bitwise_or(img, holes)
cv2.imshow('', filled_holes)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Filled holes]

Note that in this case, I just set the starting pixel for the background at `(0,0)`. However it's possible that there could be, e.g., a white line going down the center which would cut off this operation to stop filling (i.e. stop finding the background) for the other half of the image. The more robust method would be to go through all of the edge pixels on the image, and flood fill every time you come across a black pixel. You can accomplish this more easily with the `mask` parameter in `cv2.floodFill()`, which allows you to continue to update the mask each time.

---

To find the centroids of each blob, you could use contour detection and `cv2.moments()` to find the centroids of each contour, or you could also do `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()` like you mentioned.