# How does cv2.floodfill work?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

here is a example code showing usage of cv2.floodfill function

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def imshow(img):
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


img = cv2.imread('test4.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,3,1)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:-1],np.uint8)

cv2.drawContours(mask,contours,-1,(255,255,255),-1)

height, width = img.shape[:-1]

mask1 = np.zeros((height+2, width+2), np.uint8)     # line 26
cv2.floodFill(mask,mask1,(0,0),255)     # line 27
mask_inv=cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

imshow(mask_inv)
```

i am using this function in one of me projects but i am not understanding the mask1 part of the code (line 26 and line 27 )
that is,

why do we create the mask1 with shape h+2, w+2 for a given image with height-'h' and width-'w'?(line 26)

why do we have to pass this mask1 to the cv2.floodfill function?(line 27)

here is the input and output of the example code.

input image
[image: input image]

output image
[image: output image]

please help

Comment: Possibly due to the fact that the [overload that doesn't take a mask](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0) [isn't exposed to Python](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.1/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp#L3523). (It would need to have a `CV_EXPORTS_W` in front rather than just `CV_EXPORTS`)

Comment: Note that you can just use `None` for `mask1` if you're not using the parameter.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I guess that would explain why the other overload isn't wrapped.

Comment: @DanMašek I suspect that the reason you need to include a mask with shape `(h+2, w+2)` is just so that the underlying function doesn't need to create a new padded mask each time the function is called (for the border pixels). For repeated calls, which `floodFill()` is made to do, it is better to just create the padded mask once before calling.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer for your current implementation is that you don't need to use that parameter. You can simply replace `mask1` with `None` in the call because you're not using it. Check out my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483538/5087436), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971386/5087436), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084597/5087436) to see examples of `floodFill()` without the mask parameter.

The mask parameter simply fills in *where* `floodFill()` has been applied, or in case you just want to create a mask and not modify your image. You can see an example on one of my simple projects [here](https://github.com/alkasm/magicwand/blob/master/magicwand.py) using the mask parameter. In this case I was mimicking the Adobe Photoshop Magic Wand selection tool, and so I only needed the mask and didn't want to modify the image.

What `floodFill()` does is connects a pixel to it's neighbors if the neighbors are within some threshold difference of the pixel. Four-way connectivity checks the neighbors above and below, and to the left and right. Eight-way connectivity checks the diagonal pixels in addition. This means that at border pixels, you either need a bunch of `if` statements to not check the pixels outside the border, OR, you can simply pad the image with one pixel on each side so that you don't need special cases, which both reads better in code and is faster.

Normally, this would just be done inside the function and not exposed to the user. However, `floodFill()` is designed to be called multiple times on an image if need-be, and so creating a new padded `Mat` each time it's called would make the function slow. So instead, I believe, the padding is passed on to the user so that if they call the function multiple times, the padded mask is created only once.